# Setting a button title from a multi-dimension array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, button

I have a Computer Science ISP to create a trivia game. I am trying to set a title of a button from an item in a Multi-Dimensional array. The array consists of 22 questions, type String arrays with 6 items in the array.
Looking like this :

```
let Q1:[String] = ["3","Who invented the telephone?","Rogers","Virgin Mobile","Graham Bell","Nikola Tesla","0"]
```

I have a shuffled Array that includes all 22 questions(22 Q1-Q22's) and I want a button's title to be the second item in the first array in the shuffledArray. But it gives me this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'String?'

[image]

Comment: Could you add the declaration of `shuffledArray`?

Comment: Tried putting “as! String” at the end?

Comment: `String(describing: shuffledArray[0][2])` should work too. Exactly as you did for `qLabel`

Comment: @GIJOW Never use `String(describing:)` for user-facing content. Ever.

Comment: @Alexander can you help me understand why ? Didn’t find any reference avoidance on apple docs. Thanks

Comment: @GIJOW Because it's basically an admission of "I don't really know what time it is, whatever, I hope String figures it out and displays it as I would expect. Before you know it, you display to the user "Hello, Optional("Bob")"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the compile error you are getting, I would assume that if you tried to press <kbd>option</kbd> and click on `shuffledArray`, probably, it would be of type `[[Any]]` (depends on how you are declaring it). If you know that the element should be a String, you could cast it as follows:

```
if let qLabelText = shuffledArray[0][1] as? String {
      qlabel.text = qLabelText
}
```

---

### **But**

I would note that:

- if you are pretty sure that `shuffledArray` should be an array of strings array, then you should -somehow- declare it `[[String]]` instead, thus there is no need to cast the element as string.
- However, for such a case, creating your own custom Model for such a case (template) might be a better choice of doing it as a 2D array.

For instance:

```
struct QuestionModel {
    var number: String
    var content: String

    var answer1: String
    var answer2: String
    var answer3: String
    var answer4: String

    var correctAnswer: String
}
```

<sub>Definitely, the structure of declaring the model is based on your requirement and may not be necessary to clone it as is.</sub>

You could declare your question as:

```
let question1 = QuestionModel(number: "3", content: "Who invented the telephone?", answer1: "Rogers", answer2: "Virgin Mobile", answer3: "Graham Bell", answer4: "Nikola Tesla", correctAnswer: "0")
```

Thus `shuffledArray` would be an array of `QuestionModel` (`[QuestionModel]`) instead of `[[String]]`.

Now, you could write your `newQ` function as:

```
func newQ() {
    let queestion1 = shuffledArray[0]

    qlabel.text = question1.content
    button1.setTitle(question1.answer1, for: .normal)
    button2.setTitle(question1.answer2, for: .normal)
    button3.setTitle(question1.answer3, for: .normal)
    button4.setTitle(question1.answer4, for: .normal)
}
```

Following the above approach would be more expressive and easy to work with.